# How can I speed up the curing process of Mod Podge?

Tags: technique-selection, decoupage-glue

I made a gift using Mod Podge. I just found out I have to wait 4 weeks before it cures, but I only have 2 weeks! It's sticky, and it's not shiny!

I used regular Mod Podge, Gloss (3 layers) to decoupage tissue paper to a styrofoam ball (it's a Christmas ornament, to be presented to my boss who is visiting from Germany). **It is sticky, and it's not shiny enough!** So I thought I would seal it with Ultra Mod Podge Gloss spray - but I just found out I can't put the sealer on now - **the Mod Podge I used to decoupage takes 4 weeks to cure - but I only have 2 weeks till he comes.**

Can I make it cure faster, not be sticky, and make it glossy with only 2 weeks left? If I put the Ultra Mod Podge Gloss spray on now, what will happen? Is there some other product I should use to seal it?

Comment: If a heater isn't available, hang it in the path of a fan (set on low speed and at a distance such that the fan's breeze is a gentle, constant flow of air).  Turn the ornament periodically so that different parts of its surface receive the focus of the breeze.  Heat and airflow contribute to the evaporation of the water and other binding mediums which make the product sticky to the touch.

Comment: @Elmy and Henry Taylor: you seem to give good solutions to this question - why not answer it?

Comment: @Joachim, I was posting from my phone while away from my PC, so comments were easier.  Also, my answer wasn't a complete solution.  It was an addendum to Elmy's great answer

Answer (score 3):

Please keep calm. Most products do have differences between being "fully cured" and being "cured enough to handle".

I have no first-hand experience with this particular type of ModPodge, but 2 weeks should be enough to dry. Hang / store it in a warm and dry room, preferably right in an air flow to accelerate the drying and see how the surface changes over a few days.

"In an air flow" means things like above a heater, in the path of a fan, in front of a AC unit or similar. The movement of the air is supposed to remove the moisture from the ModPodge quicker.

I wouldn't risk putting it directly into a low oven because the heat can cause other problems. If you want to try this anyways, leave the oven door open to better regulate the heat.

Comment: Placing it on top of the heater might have the disadvantage that more dust swirls around in the air which might stick to a still tacky surface.